# before pseudo classifier not working in React

Tags: css, reactjs

I wanted to apply a background image to the whole of my react app and give it an opacity.
I used the following code to do so.

```
.App::before{
   content:"";
   background-image: url("./../../public/images/watermark.jpg");
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-size: cover;
   position: absolute;
   top:0;
   left:0;
   width:100%;
   height:100%;
   z-index: -1;
   opacity: 0.1;
}
```

But when I remove the ::before pseudo classifier the background image gets applied but it affects the child components. If I use ::after even then no background is applied.
Why is it so and what can I change?

Comment: You have set `top` and `left` to position it, but it has no dimensions. Add `width` and `height`. It might work better, if you also set `position:fixed` instead of `absolute` to keep it there even when scrolling.

Comment: Have you tried applying the width and height ?

Comment: Or set `right: 0; bottom: 0` so that it covers everything.

Comment: @GabrielePetrioli I applied width and height, forgot to add here, but when I changed position from absolute to fixed and when made z-index to 0 it worked but child components got affected, when z-index is -1 it is not visible.